# Problem with px.bar using animation options

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I am developing some simple code to track disk space usage in UNIX. It currently looks like this:-

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('~/my.csv',dtype={'partition':str,'timestamp':str,'project':str,'dir':str,'age':int,'size':int},keep_default_na=False,sep='\s\;\s',engine='python')
print(df.head(10))
fig = px.bar(df, x='dir', y='size', hover_data=['age', 'project'], color='dir', animation_frame='timestamp', animation_group='partition', range_y=[0,200000000])
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['frame']['duration'] = 30
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]['transition']['duration'] = 5
fig.show()
```

And the csv input data looks like this:-

```
partition ; timestamp ; project ; dir ; age ; size
fs3 ; 5/28/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 35208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 36208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 37208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 38208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 39208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 40208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 41208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 42208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 43208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 44208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 45208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 46208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 47208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 48208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 49208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 50208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 51208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 52208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@0a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 53208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@8a ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 54208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@4p ; bora ; U_baseline ; 5 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 35208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 36208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 37208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 38208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 39208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 40208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 41208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 42208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 43208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 44208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 45208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 46208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 47208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 48208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 49208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 50208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 51208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 52208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@0a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 53208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@8a ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 54208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@4p ; bora ; U_epm ; 25 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/28/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/29/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/30/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 165208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 5/31/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/1/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/2/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@0a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@8a ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 65208345
fs3 ; 6/3/23@4p ; bora ; U_adv_vmf_ml_vr ; 50 ; 165208345
```

And it works as expected, specifically when color='dir'; however, I would prefer to have color assignments associated with the age column. But when I replace color='dir' with color='age', only one directory is displayed (the first) and the other two disappear, though, oddly, I can still move my mouse pointer over the area where they are supposed to be and still see the hover data details. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that it is because the age column is not a categorical variable. So do not specify an animation group. `px.bar(df, x='dir', y='size', hover_data=['age', 'project'], color='age', animation_frame='timestamp', range_y=[0,200000000])`

Comment: Thanks, @r-beginners ...for some reason, when I drop the dtype for age it works fine. I think there may simply be a plotly bug in play here. This is an odd one.